# Graphite - using movingAverage with groupByNode

Tags: graphite, grafana

Is there any way to use movingAverage as the callback to groupByNode with a bound 2nd argument of something like 5.  Or if not at least achieve the same result?

So when using a query like this:

```
groupByNode(some.query.* , 2, "avg")
```

I'd like to replace "avg" with something that calls movingAverage with the results of the groupByNode as the first argument and 5 as the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `groupByNode(movingAverage(some.query, 5), 2, "avg")` should be the value that you're after, since it'll be the average of the 5-minute moving averages of the individual matching series.

Comment: I guess maybe I should've explained what I'm really after.  I sometimes use movingAverage to average the last few data points to "smooth" graphs if they are very "spiky" and hard to read, especially if there are several spiky series on top of each other.

Comment: @nobled I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, you have 2 different things combined together.  `movingAverage` "smooths out" variation in a series, and `groupByNode` consolidates multiple series together.

If you want to smooth each of your underlying series, then take the average of the smoothed queries, then `groupByNode(movingAverage(some.query.*, 5), 2, "avg")` will do that for you.  If you want to first average the raw values then smooth the result, then flip it around like `movingAverage(groupByNode(some.query.*, 2, "avg"), 5)`.

Comment: If I do `groupByNode(movingAverage(some.query.*, 5), 2, "avg")` as you suggest, I'll be averaging a bunch of smoothed out graphs and while the result may be somewhat smoother than not doing that, it still can be rather spiky as in the case I'm using it it's averaging up to 100s of smoothed out series.

If I do `movingAverage(groupByNode(some.query.*, 2, "avg"), 5)` as you've also suggested I only end up with one series which negates the `groupByNode` that I want.

Does that make sense?

Comment: `movingAverage` works on a seriesList, so you should  still have the same number of series as you feed into it.  If you're only getting one series back out of it then you may have a typo in your query somewhere.